# Can wait() replace sleep() or delay()?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have two separate threads in my program and I want to make one thread (say Thread1 ) to delay 5s so that the other thread (say Thread2)can complete.But they aren't forking each other,both are separate child threads.I know i could use delay() or sleep() but can i use wait(5000) inside Thread1 to delay it 5s? or Wait() can only be called by a parent thread?

Comment: Did you read `wait()`'s documentation? For your reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html

Answer (score 6):

### wait

From [wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) manual:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t wait(int *status);
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
int waitid(idtype_t idtype, id_t id, siginfo_t *infop, int options);
```

> All of these system calls are used to wait for state **changes in a
>          child of the calling process**, and obtain information about the child
>          whose state has changed.  A state change is considered to be: the
>          child terminated; the child was stopped by a signal; or the child was
>          resumed by a signal.

So, `wait` takes a **pointer to integer** (`int(*)`), but that's used to get the return status of the child. Doing `wait(5000)` won't wait for 5 seconds. As said by [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) in the comments, doing so will *most likely* crash your program.

---

### sleep

`sleep` waits for a given amount of **seconds**, but if your `Thread1` is interrupted for more time than that (very *unlikely*, but who knows...), your `sleep` will become useless.

---

### pthread_join

To wait for a thread completion you can use [pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html). From it's manual:

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

> The pthread_join() function **waits for the thread specified by thread
>          to terminate.**  If that thread has already terminated, then
>          pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by thread
>          must be joinable.

When using `pthread` family of functions, remember to compile and link with **-pthread**.

---

Your question was: **Can wait() replace sleep() or delay()?**

Answer: **No.**.

Comment: To explicitly state this: "*Doing wait(5000) ...*" will most likely **crash** the app.

Comment: @alk Yes, agreed. I added that to the answer.